# rasterio cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio

I'm trying to run the following script to get the pixel values from a raster at point data. Everything works, except for the last line. The error I'm receiving is "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer". How to solve this?
Btw src.nodata returns -1 (type = float).

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio

path = "/Users/mauritskruisheer/Documents/GeoData/WCARO stoytelling/"

# insert water points
waterpoints_Mali = pd.read_excel(path + "DISE-AEP compiles.xlsx", header = 1)
waterpoints_Mali[['Latitude', 'Longitude']] = waterpoints_Mali[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].astype(float)

fn_river_100 = path + "Riverine Floods/inunriver_historical_000000000WATCH_1980_rp00100.tif"
fn_aqueduct = path + "y2019m07d11_aqueduct30_annual_v01.csv"

# dataframe to geodataframe (ready for plotting)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    waterpoints_Mali, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(waterpoints_Mali.Longitude, waterpoints_Mali.Latitude), crs="EPSG:4326"
)

# plot the geodata
# gdf.plot()

with rasterio.open(fn_river_100, "r+") as src:
    src.nodata = int(-1)
    

    coord_list = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(gdf["geometry"].x, gdf["geometry"].y)]
    
    gdf["value"] = [x for x in src.sample(coord_list)]
```